# Count the number of occurrence on a google sheet cell

Tags: google-sheets, count, counting, flatten, google-query-language

I am trying to count the number of occurrence on a cell but it doesn't seem to work.So for instance i have dumy_data sheet which contains the dummy data that i want to count. On another sheet test is where i want to show to results.
so i did something like this ={COUNTIF(SPLIT(dumy_data!$A$2:$A$13,","),A2)} but i get zero as the number of occurrence for lucy ken. The result suppose to be 2 as the number of occurrence not 0. Also number of occurrence of Ben should be 3

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feels like a much simpler way would be to just use arrayformula around your initial formula idea:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(SPLIT(dumy_data!$A$2:$A$13,","),A2))
```

Comment: it is possible that you were trying to do that with the { } instead of using "ARRAYFORMULA()"...

Comment: that really simplifies everything

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, dumy_data!A2:A), ",")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: can you explain this formula, where should i reference the dumy_data sheet?

Comment: try that got a forula parse error

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRAJyvo7kl-4DcxiZF99ZmGRWSm8JnwwCt1S9WukMqo/edit#gid=688577306

Comment: i've updated the permission

Comment: @user11766958 here is how you use it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DUI3oL7t-JjZMr9jFVzE5x6RcZ9dYxOvNAHRQ3ZB2hY/edit#gid=0

Comment: thanks heaps, that was very helpful of you

Comment: @player0 are you now using FLATTEN() instead of TRANSPOSE() in addition to your recent switch to INDEX() instead of ARRAYFORMULA(), just to save characters in the formula?

Comment: @MattKing yes, of course :)